# ORA-06508: PL/SQL: could not find program unit being called in Package AR_RECEIPT_API_PUB Procedure Unapply

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am getting the following error when one of the custom Oracle Concurrent program is trying to unapply the Oracle AR receipt. Please find the code snippet below.
Now if I were to check the invalid objects i do not see any AR related packages as invalid including AR_RECEIPT_API_PUB.
Any pointers would be helpful.
ORA-06508: PL/SQL: could not find program unit being called in Package AR_RECEIPT_API_PUB Procedure Unapply

```
ar_receipt_api_pub.unapply(p_api_version                     => 1.0
                          ,p_init_msg_list                   => fnd_api.g_true
                          ,p_receivable_application_id       => r_appn_cur.rcv_app_id
                          ,p_org_id                 => r_appn_cur.org_id
                          ,x_return_status                   => l_return_status
                          ,x_msg_count                       => l_msg_count
                          ,x_msg_data                        => l_msg_data);
```

Comment: Does this return any invalid objects? `SELECT Referenced_Owner, Referenced_name, Referenced_Type, AO.Status
FROM DBA_Dependencies AD
INNER JOIN DBA_OBJECTS AO on AO.Owner = AD.Owner and AO.Object_name = AD.name
WHERE AD.name = 'AR_RECEIPT_API_PUB'
ORDER BY AO.status asc;`  If not, it may be necessary to recompile all of the objects in the list something may just be "Corrupted" and need  arebuild

Comment: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:637156098168  `SELECT * FROM ALL_Errors; ` may also show something of value.

Comment: Sounds like Oracle Applications to me (maybe EBS). Did you grant execute privileges to APPS user?

Comment: If I remember, _PUB in EBS is usually a synonym. SO, first check the synonym first - select * from dba_synonyms where synonym_name = 'AR_RECEIPT_API_PUB'; IS it pointing to the right one?

Then, in sqlplus, "DESC AR_RECEIPT_API_PUB' and check the procedure "UNAPPLY" is there, and you have provided all the correct parameters.

Answer (score 0):

if the package exist and have no errors, problably the user is trying to use it , has no access to it. just to verify, try creating public synonym for the package and try it.

Answer (score 0):

have u ensured that all the required api parameters are being set.
You are getting the error may be because compiler is not able to find the exact declaration of the package.